# Modelica annotation inverse conditional

Tags: annotations, conditional-statements, modelica

I have a function that does or does not have a derivative and inverse, depending on values of some parameters/coefficients. Can I make the annotations derivative and inverse conditional somehow?
Something like

```
function y_from_x
input Real x;
input Boolean hasInverse;
output Real y;
...
equation
...
annotation(inverse(x=x_from_y(y=y) if hasInverse));
end y_from_x;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *direct* support for that in the Modelica specification.
What you could do is something like:

```
function y_from_x
  input Real x;
  input Boolean hasInverse;
  output Real y;
...
algorithm
  y:=if hasInverse then y_from_x1(x) else y_from_x2(x);
  annotation(Inline=true);
end y_from_x;

function y_from_x1
  input Real x;
  output Real y;
  ...
algorithm
   y:=y_from_x2(x);
  annotation(inverse(x=x_from_y(y=y)));
end y_from_x1;

function y_from_x2
  input Real x;
  output Real y;
  ...
algorithm
  ...
end y_from_x2;
```